# Karma test runner error: "An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: _fs2.default.readdirSync is not a function"

Tags: node.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, browserify

I have been trying to trigger the browser and open Google using Karma with Jasmine.

Karma console is giving the following error:
[Karma error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBnPp.png)

Selenium-standalone log:
[Selenium standalone log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JCsT.jpg)

Karma.conf.js->

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

```
// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',

plugins: [
        'karma-browserify',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-firefox-launcher'
        ],


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['browserify','jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
'../../../scripts/jasmineTest.spec.js'
],


// list of files / patterns to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
    '../../../scripts/jasmineTest.spec.js' : [ 'browserify' ]
},

browserify: {
  debug: true,
//  transform: [ 'brfs' ]
},

// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Firefox'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false,

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
concurrency: Infinity
```

})
}

## My Jasmine script:

var wdio = require('../webdriverio')

describe("Jasmine test", function(){

var client = {}

```
client = wdio.remote({
    desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox'  
    }
})

client.init()

client.url("https://www.google.co.in")

it("test-1", function(done){
    // expect(false).not.toBe(true)
    // expect(2).toEqual(2)
    done()
})

it("test-2", function(done){
    // var a = ['A','B','C']
    // expect(a).toContain('D')
    done()
})
```

})